# workflow for creating sculpted tileable Tiles in blender?

Tags: texture-baking, sculpting, tilesize

As a sculpted tile I want it to be exported just as a OBJ textured quad, And I want to use Blender to bake also NormalMap, HeightMap, AmbientOcclusion.

How do I carefully sculpt my tile? (not necessarily by raising/decreasing only height: even custom morphing is allowed, in that case the baked texture should be projected from top anyway) as long as the final exported result is:

- **1 quad** (2 triangles)
- tileable **diffuse texture** (do I have to paint it before or after the tile?)
- tileable **normal map**
- tileable **height map**
- tileable **ambient occlusion map**

Any tecnique is fine.

everything should be baked, exporting the tile as a high poly mesh is not my goal (Even though it could be a desiderable option in a future time) since this is for a mobile game using physically based shaders.

Answer (score 1):

I checked also on blender forum. There is currently no simple workflow. Some workflows require offseting the mesh to sculpt over seams.

Seems there's a patch for the issue submitted in 2015, but seems it was not officially accepted yet.

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?373956-Wrap-mode-for-Sculpt

If anyone has any idea on how to do that he is wellcome anyway^^.

Seriously thinking to try to write my own plugin, unluckily I'm totally new to Blender python API